# If Gatling has an assertion fail during a maven build it will not reach the `post-integration-test` phase, which leaves spring-boot running

Tags: maven, spring-boot, performance-testing, gatling

I'm using the failsafe plugin for integration tests, which works well during a test failure.  The `post-integration-test` phase is executed, which calls `spring-boot:stop`.  Using the same pattern, I want to do performance testing with Gatling.  It appears as though the `gatling-maven-plugin` does not have this same functionality and a failure during the `integration-test` phase will not guarantee that `post-integration-test` gets called.  As a result, the spring-boot app is still running and a subsequent run will fail to start.

I've scoured the internet for hours looking for a solution but they all only take it half way.  They show how to execute the gatling tests but do not show how to recover during a failure.

Is this capability possible with the gatling plugin? If not, how can I invoke the `post-integration-test` phase directly after a maven build failure?

Answer (score 0):

A sufficient workaround is to configure the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` to not fork.  My application stopped as expected during a build failure (due to gatling assertion failure) and during a build success.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>repackage</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
              <execution>
                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>start</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
              <execution>
                <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>stop</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

.

```
<profile>
    <id>performance</id>
    <properties>
      <skip.integration.tests>true</skip.integration.tests>
      <skipTests>true</skipTests>
    </properties>
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <fork>false</fork>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
          <artifactId>gatling-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${gatling-plugin.version}</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <goals>
                <goal>execute</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```